# req.body in nodejs API is empty when data is posted via JQuery

Tags: jquery, node.js

So here I have an API that takes a link of an image an compresses that image using a third party API, the API gets the link thus; `req.body.link`. The problem is when i send data via jQuery and ajax, the data does not reach the the API, i tried to console.log(req.body) and it showed {}...but when I use Postman, console.log(req.body) returns a body with data.

With Postman, everything works fine...the problem starts when i call the API on the .NET webapp with jQuery.

I've tried JSON.stringify(), I've tried the $.ajax method

Heres the nodejs code

```
app.post('/upload',(req,res)=>{
    opts={
        url:req.body.link,
        wait:true,
        lossy:true,
        quality:60
    };

    kraken.url(opts,(err,data)=>{

        if(err){
            res.json([{"Status":"Failed"},{"Message":"Forbidden file format"}]);
        }else{
            res.json(data);
        }

    });

});
```

and below is the jQuery code (I already tried $.ajax)

```
    var url = `https://www.example.info/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/19/04.jpg`;

    $.post('http://localhost:5000/upload/', {"link":url}, function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

Comment: What content type did you use in Postman? Default for `$.ajax` methods (including `$.post`) is form encoded

Comment: Are backticks valid string literal delimiters in JS?

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes...known as *template literals*

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks, another good learning day

Comment: @charlietfl content type on postman is application/json

Comment: So in node you can use `bodyParser.urlencoded(/*options*/)` or change to using `$.ajax` and send as json and set contentType yourself

Answer (score 0):

It usually happens that APIs are working fine from headless tools like Postman or rest-client but not working from code/browser,
the reason could be that you have not handles cors properly, try with one npm module "cors"
and register your apis as below in node.js

```
var cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors())
```

Can you share your node.js code also?